# XmlDataSource No Data Condition

Tags: asp.net

How do I write a condition for when an XmlDataSource does not return any data to my Repeater control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an empty data template for the Repeater.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=271&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1